# C++ socket keeps receiving the same data

Tags: c++, sockets, sensors

I am using this code to receive data from a sensor  through sockets. The problem is that I keep receiving the same output for every iteration of the for loop. However I receive a different number for every time I run the code but again, the same number keeps repeating. The sensor should send different every time data but thats not the case here.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include "port.h"

#define BUFSIZE 2048

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct sockaddr_in myaddr;  /* our address */
    struct sockaddr_in remaddr; /* remote address */
    socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(remaddr);        /* length of addresses */
    int recvlen;            /* # bytes received */
    int fd;             /* our socket */
    int msgcnt = 0;         /* count # of messages we received */
    unsigned char buf[BUFSIZE]; /* receive buffer */


    /* create a UDP socket */

    if ((fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("cannot create socket\n");
        return 0;
    }

    /* bind the socket to any valid IP address and a specific port */

    memset((char *)&myaddr, 0, sizeof(myaddr));
    myaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    myaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    myaddr.sin_port = htons(SERVICE_PORT);

    if (bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&myaddr, sizeof(myaddr)) < 0) {
        perror("bind failed");
        return 0;
    }

    /* now loop, receiving data and printing what we received */

    printf("waiting on port %d\n", SERVICE_PORT);
        printf("%s \n \n", "We recieve 10 packets just to confirm the communication");


    recvlen = recvfrom(fd, buf, BUFSIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&remaddr, &addrlen);
        if (recvlen > 0) {
            buf[recvlen] = 0;
            printf("received message: \"%u\" (%d bytes)\n", buf, recvlen);
        }
        else
            printf("uh oh - something went wrong!\n");
        sprintf(buf, "ack %d", msgcnt++);
        printf("sending response \"%u\"\n", buf);
        if (sendto(fd, buf, strlen(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&remaddr, addrlen) < 0)
            perror("sendto");

    int temp = recvlen;

    for (;;) {

    recvlen = recvfrom(fd, buf, BUFSIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&remaddr, &addrlen);
    if (recvlen > 0) {
            buf[recvlen] = 0;
            printf("received message: \"%u\" (%d bytes)\n", buf, recvlen);

    }



}
}
```

Edit:
Here is the output when i ran the code two seperate times:
[trial run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdAdJ.png) and 
[trial run 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clBMF.png)

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code. The random, haphazard indentation makes your code nearly impossible to understand.

Comment: sorry about that! im using codeblocks on ubuntu and ive tried so hard to indent it but it doesnt seems to work. thank you for the feedback though

Comment: You also need to explain clearly what your problem is. You write, and I quote verbatim: "However I receive a different number for every time I run the code but again, the same number keeps repeating." What number? Where is that number? Is it different each time? Or is it the same number each time? What exactly is the number that you see?  What number do you expect to see? Why do you expect to see that particular number? This is utterly incomprehensible.

Comment: @user3238603 Since you're doing socket programming, you really should be using your debugger (if it has a memory window, use that) to inspect the data you're receiving, and not use `printf` or other output statements.  Using `printf` is faulty in that you can get something wrong (like the wrong format specifier), or the `printf` itself doesn't show all the data due to the data being sent back having embedded nulls.

Comment: Its a sensor that sends unsigned ints. so the number is irrelevant but it should be different in each iteration. i updated the question with two trial runs please check them out @SamVarshavchik

Comment: Since you are using C++:
`std::cout << "bytes received: "; std::cout.write(buf, recvlen); cout << '\n';`  This will write all of the bytes that you received (at least, no characters will be missed on the output).  However, the debugger is the much better tool for this.

Comment: Why are you printing and sending even in the 'uh-oh something went wrong' case?

Comment: Your sensor sends 140-odd bytes at a time, but you are printing only the first `int` worth of bytes and discard the rest. Do you know the messsage format? Are you sure yorr data always occupies just the first four bytes of the message?

Comment: Further, you are receiving binary data, but you are terminating your buffer with a null character and using strlen on it. You need to decide whether your message is a null-terminated C string or an arbitrary bunch of bytes, and stick to that decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem isn't with your networking code but rather with your printf() calls:

```
        printf("received message: \"%u\" (%d bytes)\n", buf, recvlen);
```

You are specifying `%u` to print out the contents of `buf`, but buf is a char array (not an unsigned integer), so you probably want to be using `%s` instead.

Comment: I already tried that. All i recieve is "". I am glad to know the socket communication is correct though that means the problem is with the sensor maybe! if you check out the trial runs even though i recieve the same number each time but the size is different for some reason.

Comment: @user3238603 Using `%s` is also faulty.  If you read my comments in the main section, the `%s` will stop at the first embedded null.  Don't use `printf`  -- use your debugger.  You're not printing all of your data, which is why you are not getting things to match up.

Comment: If you receive binary data, you should loop over the bytes and do something like `printf("%02x", buf[i])`.

Comment: Another thing to do is run WireShark so you can see the contents of the packets that are coming in.  That will let you verify that the data in the incoming packets is what you expect it to be (or not).